# Authentication at SQL vs Server (Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword /HashBytes)

Tags: c#, t-sql, security

I have an application that stores hashed passwords in the database.The applicatin is written in .Net and It uses SQL Server 2012.The authentication workflow is as follows:

- Users types Email Address/Password
- Database Call is done to retrieve the record by email Address
- Servers side verification of the stored hashed password against the password that is typed using this code:

  Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(hashedPassword, password);

I am wondering whether this can be done solely in the database and what are the disadvantages of that approach. I understand that i will be sending clear text passwords to the TSQL Stored Procedure.

I was reading about HashBytes and it seems a candidate for hashing. It seems that I can hash it and convert it to NVARCHAR field and do a comparison on that as follows:

```
SELECT 
....
FROM dbo.Users 
WHERE EmailAddress = '<Entered_EmailAddress>' 
  AND Password = master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(HashBytes('SHA2_256', '<Entered_Password>' ))
```

Comment: You should use an iterated, salted hash.

Comment: Currently, the app does that. I use Crypto.HashPassword before I store in the database. 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto.hashpassword(v=vs.111).aspx